# Merge walls into unifed mesh with corners normalization

Tags: algorithm, 3d, three.js, dart, dart-editor

I'm working on some simple building planning editor. For 3D preview I'm using Three.js library for Dart (from GitHib). So far algorithm is pretty simple: it converts single lines to rectangles and then extrude it (based on thickness and height).

[image: Problem with corsners]

Is it possible to normalize vertex position depending on adjacent walls? Technically I store list of walls, within can query adjacent walls and can calculate Vector2 list for mesh generation for each wall. I have to apply changes to each wall separately due to extrusion.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could instead try to properly tessellate the 2D thickened walls, and then only extrude them (instead of extruding, tessellating and then trying to fix the joints). For simple polylines, joint tessellation can be handled like described in this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/226569/Drawing-polylines-by-tessellation.

Comment: That's great article, thanks! Any ideas about multiply walls though?

Comment: @Freight5 You mean when multiple walls are adjacent and meet at a single point? Then the geometric construction described in the linked article for the inner part of the joint would also apply, I believe. You need to order the walls around the meeting point, though.